# RxJava and Retrofit - Raising custom exceptions depending on server response

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I would like Retrofit to raise custom exceptions depending on the server response. For example in the following structure:

```
{
"code":0,
"message":"OK",
"data":{....}
}
```

I would like to raise an exception for subscribers if `code` is anything other than 0. How is it possible using Retrofit and Rx? I would much prefer to write this logic only once and have it applied to all observables returned by retrofit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I would like to raise an exception for subscribers if code is anything other than 0. How is it possible using Retrofit and Rx?

You can use a [`Observable.flatMap`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#flatMap(rx.functions.Func1)) operator:

```
api.request().flatMap(response -> {
    if (response.getCode() != 0) {
        return Observable.error(new Exception("Remote error occurred"));
    }

    return Observable.just(response);
});
```

> I would much prefer to write this logic only once and have it applied to all observables returned by retrofit.

Unfortunately, there is not way to do it using `retrofit` and `rx-java`. You **have** to write the code above for every `retrofit` call. The only thing you can do is to use [`Observable.compose`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#compose(rx.Observable.Transformer)) method and reduce the amount of boilerplate you actually have to write.

```
api.request().compose(new ResponseTransformer<Response>());
```

And here is the `ResponseTransformer` class:

```
public static class ResponseTransformer<T extends Response> implements Observable.Transformer<T, T> {
    @Override
    public Observable<T> call(final Observable<T> observable) {
        return observable.flatMap(response -> {
            if (response.getCode() != 0) {
                return Observable.error(new Exception("Remote error occurred"));
            }

            return Observable.just(response);
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Well, as I said, there is no way to avoid boilerplate code using only `retrofit` and `rxjava`, but you can workaround it with [dynamic proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html) (note that you don't need to call `compose` anymore):

```
final Api api = restAdapter.create(Api.class);

final ClassLoader loader = api.getClass().getClassLoader();
final Class<?>[] interfaces = api.getClass().getInterfaces();

final Api proxy = (Api) Proxy.newProxyInstance(loader, interfaces, new ResponseInvocationHandler(api));

proxy.request().subscribe(response -> {
    System.out.println("Success!");
});
```

`ResponseInvocationHandler` class:

```
public static class ResponseInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    private final Object target;

    public ResponseInvocationHandler(final Object target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
    public Object invoke(final Object proxy, final Method method, final Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        final Object result = method.invoke(target, args);

        if (result instanceof Observable) {
            return Observable.class.cast(result).compose(new ResponseTransformer<>());
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nima check my updated answer, it could be even more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different approach.

You will need to implement a custom OkHttp client with custom Interceptor.

```
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.interceptors().add(new MyInterceptor());
        mAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(Consts.ENDPOINT).setClient(new OkClient(client))
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.BASIC).build();
```

In your interceptor depending on the code returned you can proceed normally or throw an exception.

Something like this:

```
public class MyInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());

        if(response.code() == 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Something went wrong!");
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: That sounds like a promising solution, but there is one big issue with it. `okhttp` interceptors work on `http` level and the value return by `response.code()` is actually a http code, not the code from the `json`.  In order to extract the real code you have to parse the json (which is bad idea because then it will be parsed again by `retrofit` convertor).

Comment: @VladimirMironov yes it is the http code. If you are returning a simple json   ,with just 3 fields like in your question, parsing it twice shouldn't be a problem. If there is something more complicated maybe you'll need a better solution

Answer (score 0):

1 custom `Observable.Operator` :

```
public class YourOperator implements Observable.Operator{  
    public void onNext(Data data){  
        if (data.code != 0 ){  
            //raise your custom Exception  
        }  
    }  
    public void onError(Throwable e){  
        //handler Exception  
    }  
}
```

2 user like:

```
api.youRequest()
    .lift(new YourOperator())
    .subscribe(....);
```